# How to NOT center android dialog?

Tags: android, xml, dialog, xamarin, android-animation

I want to use a dialog but I don't want it to be centered vertically on the screen.

I created a `Dialog` and used `SetContentView()` to apply the layout.
I also applied style and no title option.  Here is what I did.

```
mydialog = new Dialog (context, Resource.Style.myDialogAnim);
mydialog.RequestWindowFeature ((int)WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
mydialog.SetContentView (myDialogView);
mydialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside (false);
```

The style I applied to this dialog is here:

```
<style name="myDialogAnim" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/slideInAndOut</item>
     <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
<style name="slideInAndOut">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/anim_animatein</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/anim_animateaway</item>
</style>
```

When I use this dialog, the dialog animates in from the `fromYDelta` location to the `toYDelta` location in `anim_animatein` but as soon as the animation is done, it centers itself vertically.

I need it to be centered horizontally on the screen but NOT vertically.

How can I do this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: make a custom dialog activity : use dialogParentLayout.setY() to set its  axis.

Comment: That was one option but I was trying to find a way around creating a new activity.  Dialog Activity just wasn't necessary for me.  As you can see the answer below, I found a way around. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
WindowManagerLayoutParams dialogParams = mydialog.Window.Attributes;
dialogParams.Gravity = GravityFlags.Bottom;
int dialogYPos = 69 * (int)activity.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
dialogParams.Y = dialogYPos;
```

`dialogYPos` returns how many `pixels` you want it to move up from it's location.  So I set it's `Gravity` to `Bottom` so it's that many `pixels` from the bottom of the screen.

**Extra:**
Since I am using the dialog as just a floating message, I wanted the user to be able to use the current activity when the dialog is showing.  I added the following flag and it worked perfecly.

`mydialog.Window.AddFlags (WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchModal);`

Now I am using a `Dialog` as an android `Toast` Widget with my animation and complete customization.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I think dialog is very heavy thing which is used in very big things in android to show what big this was happend, like Logout-BatteryLow, Have you ever seen dialogs in Google app. i will suggest you to use Appmsg library of RomanNurik to show localApp msg like Toast.

Comment: I actually tried to use standard Android `Toast` widget but I couldn't get the animation and style to work.  That's why I decided to go with a `Dialog`. But I will look into this option.  https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/undobar  Thanks!!